# Looking for a hook for post.php

Tags: hooks, actions

First time posting here...

I am trying to figure out if there is a hook or action that I can use when a user goes to wp-admin/post.php... Basically when the user goes to post.php I want to check if there is a &from=1 variable and add that to post_meta

Thanks!

```
$from = $_GET['from'];
$post_id = $_GET['post'];
if($from == 1){
  add_post_meta($post_id, 'EDITED', 'true');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add your code to the `init` action hook and check global `$pagenow` variable:

```
add_action( 'init', 'wpse8170_check_from_var' );
function wpse8170_check_from_var() {
    global $pagenow;

    if ( 'post.php' != $pagenow || ! isset( $_GET['post'] ) || ! isset( $_GET['from'] ) || 1 != (int) $_GET['from'] ) {
        return;
    }

    update_post_meta( (int) $_GET['post'], 'EDITED', 'true' );
}
```

Comment: Updated your code. Removed the pull `get_post()` as the check is not needed because if the `post id` doesn't exist `update_post_meta()` will take care of that. Also took care of your if statements so no longer deeply nested.

Comment: Why did you re-edit and add `{}` to the if statement? They are not needed if the code running, when the condition is met, is one line only.

Comment: @Brady I prefer to use brace even for one line only. It   enhances readability and makes code styles look the same.

Comment: Do you guys think this would be more efficient to use the edit_post hook rather then init which checks on every page load??? So the post meta is only updated to EDITED upon updates?